# What is the use of standing waves in organ pipes, whether the sound is due to standing waves?

Tags: waves, acoustics

Using standing waves we create formula for harmonics . If it is true then how is frequency of standing wave is determined when standing wave is not moving.

Answer (score 1):

Frequencies are determined by solving the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) for a tube/cylinder/rope with boundary conditions that the amplitudes vanishes on the surfaces/edges.

A useful tip: Don't consider sound waves moving *per se* - rather as particles being wobbled around by the wave and transmitting the wave to its neightbouring particles

Answer (score 0):

The formation of standing waves is, as *DrLRX* states, the steady-state solutions of the wave equation (you can have a look at the [solution due to Bernoulli](https://planetmath.org/solvingthewaveequationduetodbernoulli)). Now, [d'Alembert's solution](http://www-solar.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~alan/MT2003/PDE/node12.html) states that the solution to the wave equation constitutes the superposition of two travelling waves in opposite directions. Since we are talking about the solutions to the same equation, you can think that they are conceptually the same thing (forgive the mathematical abuse here).

Since this is the way to create standing waves, you can very well see that they can be represented by the superposition of a travelling wave and its reflection off a boundary (in fact you need a closed path to get a standing wave solution, such as room-modes). The frequency of those travelling waves (which is the same for both) is what we refer to as the frequency of the standing wave.

In addition to that, you should keep in mind that, although a standing wave is seen as a non-travelling "wave" (quite true in the physical/mathematical sense, as there is no energy transport - points of zero intensity - for the ideal lossless case), the particles are still vibrating in the frequency of the original travelling waves in every point except for the nodal ones!